# Is returning by reference of a member variable EVER acceptable?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, reference, ownership

Suppose I have:

```
class Metadata {
    // stores expensive-to-copy data, provides complex interface to access/modify
}

class SomeObject
public:
    Metadata& GetMetadata() { return mMetadata; }
private:
    Metadata mMetadata;
}

boost::shared_ptr<SomeObject> obj = ...;
obj->GetMetadata().SetTitle("foo");
obj->GetMetadata().GetTitle();
```

The universal consensus seems to be that returning by reference, especially non-const, is extremely bad in all but a few specific situations. However, in this case, it appears to be the best (and only?) option:

1. I don't want to return a copy, since I want to modify the *original* (and even if it was r/o, copying is to expensive).
2. I don't want to return a Metadata* or anything like it, since I don't want to encourage a pointer being stored or passed around.
3. I don't want to pollute the interface to SomeObject with irrelevant wrapper calls to Metadata.

It introduces a vague requirement that SomeObject be able to pass back a Metadata by reference, meaning there must be a Metadata object whose lifetime is coterminous with (or longer than) the lifetime of SomeObject - however, that's the exact semantic relationship between the objects, and requiring that certainly better than any of the above options.

It occurred to me that I could introduce some kind of non-copyable pointer type and return that, but that smells funny / seems like overkill. I could make SomeObject own a boost::shared_ptr, but this really isn't a good match for the semantics I had in mind (basically: if you're modifying now, modify the original - if you're reading later / storing, make a copy and keep track yourself).

Is there a better pattern to use here? Will I be shooting myself in the foot in some way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Who told you this was bad? Returning references to class data members is a ubiquitous and useful programming technique.

Comment: I don't see a problem with returning non-const references. Although it may be simpler to just make the member variable public.

Comment: Given that `Metadata` already encapsulates the raw data, it may also be perfectly fine to just make `mMetadata` a public member of `SomeObject` (preferably with a better name) and use it directly instead of going through a `GetMetadata()` (which doesn't seem to accomplish anything in this case).

Comment: @KerrekSB Scott Meyers did (Effective C++ item 28). Although he does say there are exceptions like vector.

Comment: Wrapper calls to `Metadata` might be unnecessary but they shouldn't be "irrelevant" otherwise `Metadata` doesn't belong in `SomeObject`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - My intuition, and subsequent arguing with myself, told me I had the right answer. I was surprised when looking around that the practice was pretty universally discouraged (in general cases at least - a search on SO pretty much yields "just don't" responses), and was curious if there were alternative design patterns or gotchas that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: I'm still intrigued by the idea of returning a non-copyable, non-constructible pointer as an alternative. A pointer-like object would be slightly more agnostic to object lifetime changes in the future than &, and would allow e.g. adding scoped_lock like behavior if I needed thread safety (which I *almost* did in the case I was looking at).

Comment: @scztt: "lifetime agnostic" sounds like the worst of all worlds. If anything, you want the exact opposite: Lifetime guarantees as part of the type system, as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to return a reference to something that will outlive the function call. When you return an lvalue reference to a class data member, just make sure the class instance is itself an lvalue:

```
struct Foo
{
    X data;

    X & the_data() &   { return data; }
//                ^^^
```

While you're at it, you can also return the data as an rvalue if your instance is an rvalue:

```
    X && the_data() && { return std::move(data); }
};
```

Comment: @T.C.: D'oh, yes. Or `std::move(*this).data` :-) More idiomatic (move the thing bound to the rvalue).

Comment: Naturally, returning by `const X&` to avoid needless copying of returned values is also common.

Comment: TIL you could require an lvalue like that. I learn something new about C++ everyday.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know about the varieties of l/rvalue usage.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, returning a reference is preferred for performance as long as you aren't returning reference to a local (automatic) storage. You should be returning a `const` reference in most cases.

This allows C++ compiler (which is an aggressively optimizing language compiler by design) to optimize away many things, and also allows writing "fluent" syntax.

```
obj.foo().bar().baz();
```

Comment: I disagree. I think you should actually have a good reason to return a reference and returning by-value should be preferred. Better encapsulation, looser coupling, less chance of errors, etc. Clearly there are reasons to return by reference however.

Comment: @ChrisDrew If we are talking exclusively modern C++ with rvalue reference and move semantics, then I agree with you. And certainly on the coupling, though I typically don't hide any internal types. What type of objects do you propose it is better to return copies by default? Most of the code I work with uses a lot of internal handles or containers and node pointers so I prefer not to copy by default.

Comment: I'd say it would be a reasonable default choice to return by-value for fundamental types, small strings, tiny objects, anytime you can get the return-value-optimization and anytime you can move. So that mostly leaves the case where you want to avoid forwarding calls to a medium-to-large sized internal object and are willing to break encapsulation. Which might be exactly OP's situation.

Comment: Edited. on further thought, I agree my statement was a too strong to be useful. In practicality, I don't think there is any default approach, just the appropriate approach. I work with a lot of fat objects or with nested containers, DAGs and ASTs, so I use mostly pointers and refs, but my class is probably atypical.